Can't comprehend the logic of Bead Challenge on InterviewBit
So I've been practicing few coding question on InterviewBit and I came across 'Bead Challenge'. Here's the questions:
You possess a vector A of size N, where Ai denotes the weight of the i-th bead among n beads on a table. Engaging in a competition against a machine, you have the liberty to select any two beads, keeping one for yourself (Ai) and surrendering the other to the machine (Aj). If you choose to retain Ai, you can partition its weight into k beads of equal weight (resulting in a new weight of Ai/k for the i-th bead). However, you must keep one of these new beads and discard the remaining k-1 beads. Subsequently, the machine will amplify the weight of the j-th bead (initially Aj) to k times its original weight (kAj). The objective is to achieve equal weights for all beads through a series of operations. Return 1 if successful or 0 if unsuccessful in this challenge.
And here is an example:
Let's examine the vector A, which is [100, 2, 50, 10, 1], containing 5 elements. Two operations are performed on it:
Select a3 (which is 50) and a2 (which is 2), with k as 5. Replace a3 with a3 / k, resulting in 10, and replace a2 with a2 * k, resulting in 10. The modified array is now [100, 10, 10, 10, 1].
Choose a1 (which is 100) and a5 (which is 1), with k as 10. Replace a1 with a1 / k, resulting in 10, and replace a5 with a5 * k, resulting in 10. The final array is [10, 10, 10, 10, 10].
I did understand the question, but couldn't come up with a solution. So I looked into the solution the platform had to offer:
from collections import defaultdict
def secreatFunction(x, divs):
    i = 2
    while i * i <= x:
        while x % i == 0:
            divs[i] += 1
            x //= i
        i += 1
    if x > 1:
        divs[x] += 1

class Solution:
    def solve(self, A):
        a=defaultdict(int)
        n=len(A)
        for i in A:
            secreatFunction(i, a)
        for count in a.values():
            if count % n != 0:
                return 0
        return 1


I tried comprehending the code logic using pen and paper, and yes I do understand how the solution call for a case where a given prime factor can be equally distributed among all the beads (or all the elements in the array). But I can't map the code logic to the question logic. Can somebody help me out?
